# Меню при щелчке правой кнопкой мыши

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, файлы, winapi

Как при щелчке ПКМ по исполняемому exe файлу (собранному в visual studio на c#) к стандартному контекстному меню (свойства, копировать, изменить и тд) добавить свои пункты ?

Comment: Если я не ошибаюсь, вам в сторону WinAPI смотреть надо

Comment: @AGS17 Я тоже предполагал что c# слишком высокоуровневый для такого. Но ничего конкретного не нашел

Comment: @Сергей а зачем метка winforms?

Comment: Приложение будет собрано по шаблону WinForms.  Возможно это и не важно, но тк я пока не в теме то на всякий случай указал.

Comment: @Сергей если вы правильно описали свой вопрос, то ответ "никак". Вы можете добавить свои пункты в стандартное контекстное меню только _для всех_ *.exe файлов, и это легко делается через реестр. И C# тут не поможет, так как ваше приложение даже не будет запущено при открытии этого меню.

Comment: @Nikita Никак вообще или никак именно с# .NET ?

Comment: Вообще, по этому вопросу есть интересная статья на geektimes. Статья старенькая но достаточно подробная, описывает по шагам как добавить команды в контекстное меню проводника в windows 7 (сработает и для 10).[Собственно, ссылка.](https://geektimes.ru/post/79443/) А Если нужно именно программно это делать, то манипуляциями с winapi получить окно контекстного меню и изменить его наполнение руками.

Comment: Вопрос немного не в этом, автор хочет чтобы меню было изменено только для его конкретной программы.

Comment: Добавить пункты нужно именно в файл моей программы, не могу же я лазить по реестру всех кто будет ей пользоваться.

Comment: @Сергей это меню относится целиком к Windows, оно никак не связано с вашей программой, так что от языка и платформы приложения это не зависит. Конечно, вы можете при установке вашего приложения и в процессе его работы изменять эти пункты _программно_ через реестр. Но измененное меню будет доступно  в том числе и при клике на другие exe.

Comment: @Nikita При клике ПКМ на архивном файле появляется, например пункт меню "Извлечь в текущую папку" при клике ПКМ на любые другие exe, не являющиеся архивом такого пункта не будет. Значит меню можно поменять для определенного типа файлов и почти наверняка для одного определенного.

Comment: @Сергей так я же вам то же самое выше написал: "Вы можете добавить свои пункты в стандартное контекстное меню _только для всех *.exe файлов_" (по аналогии с архивными расширениями .rar .zip и т.д.). Для одного конкретного файла с расширением exe не получится.

Comment: и для этого совершенно необходимо лезть в реестр?